# Python : send data of form to one email address

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I write a form in Google App Engine using Python that user can input data to form. After input, I want this data to be send to one's email. for example : example@gmail.com.

My question is : in Python, does it have simple function (and I can use this function on Google App Engine) to send email ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python does have a mail package for transmitting emails.

Included below is an example as found in the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html)

```
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import smtplib

# Import the email modules we'll need
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# Open a plain text file for reading.  For this example, assume that
# the text file contains only ASCII characters.
fp = open(textfile, 'rb')
# Create a text/plain message
msg = MIMEText(fp.read())
fp.close()

# me == the sender's email address
# you == the recipient's email address
msg['Subject'] = 'The contents of %s' % textfile
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Send the message via our own SMTP server, but don't include the
# envelope header.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(me, [you], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

In addition, the app engine has a [mail API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/) as well.

```
from google.appengine.api import mail

mail.send_mail(sender="Example.com Support <support@example.com>",
              to="Albert Johnson <Albert.Johnson@example.com>",
              subject="Your account has been approved",
              body="""
Dear Albert:

Your example.com account has been approved.  You can now visit
http://www.example.com/ and sign in using your Google Account to
access new features.

Please let us know if you have any questions.

The example.com Team
""")
```